# How do I fix a ProgrammingError at /admin/login/ (1146, "Table 'torquedb.showroom_customuser' doesn't exist")

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I created a CustomUser using the Django allAuth package. Allowing users to sign-up and log in via email rather than usernames was the primary reason why.

When I try logging into the admin with my superuser account, it throws this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
(1146, "Table 'torquedb.showroom_customuser' doesn't exist")
```

**Admin.py for the customuser**

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'phone_number', 'website']
```

**The CustomUser models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default='07')
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

I've tried running new migrations with

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate

py manage.py migrate showroom (the app name)
```

I've already dropped and recreated the MariaDB database (called torquedb) a few times, and this is a new one with all migrations up to date.  Again, they all state that they are up to date.

**Update**
This issue is probably directly related to the custom user I created using Django allauth. When I tried to migrate it, this error was raised:

```
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'showroom.CustomUser' cannot be resolved
```

Even though all other migrations worked fine. So I ran `py manage.py migrate --fake` to fake the migration and everything else worked fine.

I know faking migrations doesn't actually **make** the migrations, which is the problem, but I can't still can't figure out how to solve it.

After purging the database and starting afresh, this is the error produced.

```
(torque) C:\code\torque>py manage.py makemigrations                                                                                                                                             No changes detected                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             (torque) C:\code\torque>py manage.py migrate showroom                                                                                                                                           Operations to perform:                                                                                                                                                                            Apply all migrations: showroom                                                                                                                                                                Running migrations:                                                                                                                                                                               Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                        Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK                                                                                                                                       Applying auth.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                                Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK                                                                                                                                       Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK                                                                                                                                            Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK                                                                                                                                               Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK                                                                                                                                             Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK                                                                                                                                              Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK                                                                                                                                    Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK                                                                                                                                         Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK                                                                                                                                        Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK                                                                                                                                            Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK                                                                                                                                               Applying showroom.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                            Applying account.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                             Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK                                                                                                                                                    Applying account.0003_auto_20191015_1328... OK                                                                                                                                                  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                               Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK                                                                                                                                              Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK                                                                                                                                      Applying admin.0004_auto_20191015_1328... OK                                                                                                                                                    Applying sites.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                               Applying socialaccount.0001_initial... OK                                                                                                                                                       Applying socialaccount.0002_token_max_lengths... OK                                                                                                                                             Applying socialaccount.0003_extra_data_default_dict... OK                                                                                                                                       Applying socialaccount.0004_auto_20191015_1328... OK                                                                                                                                            Applying showroom.0002_auto_20191015_1328...Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                                                                                                            main()                                                                                                                                                                                        File "manage.py", line 17, in main                                                                                                                                                                execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                           File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line                                                                     utility.execute()                                                                                                                                                                             File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute                                                                                       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                                                                                                                       File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv                                                                                     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)                                                                                                                                                            File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute                                                                                           output = self.handle(*args, **options)                                                                                                                                                        File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped                                                                                            res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                            File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle                                                                                fake_initial=fake_initial,                                                                                                                                                                    File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate                                                                                         state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)                                                                                              File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards                                                                           state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)                                                                                                          File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration                                                                                 state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)                                                                                                                                                 File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply                                                                                          operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)                                                                                                          File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards                                                                      schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)                                                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 507, in alter_field                                                                                    new_db_params = new_field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)                                                                                                                           File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 966, in db_parameters                                                                                 return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}                                                                                                                 File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 963, in db_type                                                                                       return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)                                                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 878, in target_field                                                                                  return self.foreign_related_fields[0]                                                                                                                                                         File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 632, in foreign_related_fields                                                                        return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)                                                                                                          File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 619, in related_fields                                                                                self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()                                                                                                                                          File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\torque\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields                                                                        raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)                                                                                                           ValueError: Related model 'showroom.CustomUser' cannot be resolved
```

Then I fake the migration

```
(torque) C:\code\torque>py manage.py migrate --fake showroom                                                                                                                                    Operations to perform:                                                                                                                                                                            Apply all migrations: showroom                                                                                                                                                                Running migrations:                                                                                                                                                                               Applying showroom.0002_auto_20191015_1328... FAKED                                                                                                                                              Applying showroom.0003_auto_20191015_1329... FAKED
```

Comment: Did you change the user model in already developed project?

Comment: yes, all references across the views, forms etc... were updated

Comment: Did you check the database whether the table really exists?

Comment: I'm sure it does, but are there any additional checks to confirm?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-tables/ - or I assume there are tools which allow you a visual inspection of your database. If you don't have one yet, get one, you'll need it for other debugging purposes as well...

Comment: Oh yes, the show tables command. Yes, it does exist. I've just double-checked

Comment: I had the same problem over my heroku app, so I followed these steps, `heroku run python manage.py flush`, `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations/ then migrate/ then createsuperuser` and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) on changing to a custom user model mid-project:

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is significantly more difficult since it affects foreign keys and many-to-many relationships, for example.
>
> This change can’t be done automatically and requires manually fixing your schema, moving your data from the old user table, and possibly manually reapplying some migrations

So, I think all you need to

1. Delete all the migration files(which reside in `<any app directory>/migration`, also don't remove the `__init__.py` file from the migration directory) from all the apps
2. Drop the database and create new one.
3. re-create all the migration using `./manage.py makemigrations` and migrate using `./manage.py migrate`.

More information can be found in ticket: [`#25313`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313) where you can do the changes without loosing the data in DB. You can also checkout my [blog post](https://ruddra.com/posts/django-custom-user-migration-mid-phase-project) as well.

Also looking into your code, probably you should use:

```
@admin.register(CustomUser)
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      #               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When adding the model to admin site.

Comment: I already manually deleted the migration files in the folder and remade them from scratch.

Comment: `class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):` Instead of this, use `class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):`, can you please try with this code?

Comment: Raising " class CustomUserAdmin(admin.UserAdmin):                                                                                                                                                     AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.admin' has no attribute 'UserAdmin'" in the command-line

Comment: I imported the UserAdmin as "from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin", and I've added this to the question

Comment: there is no UserAdmin, I have used `ModelAdmin`, please see the updated answer

Comment: Okay, I've updated it in my code. Thanks for that :-). But logging in still raises the original error

Comment: Is there any additional context/code which would be helpful?

Comment: I am out of clue, maybe can you try with a different DB like postgres or MySQL?

Comment: No, that seems a little too drastic. The database works perfectly otherwise

Comment: I''ve just remembered some additional vital information which I added to the question. Would you mind looking at it?

Comment: Done. I've added the original traceback

Comment: probably you did not remove all the migration files from `migrations` folder. Its a classic problem, please see the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project or ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313. You can also checkout my blog post on this: https://ruddra.com/posts/django-custom-user-migration-mid-phase-project/

Comment: Exactly what happened. There was an existing migration which I deleted manually

Comment: Please edit this into the answer so I can mark it complete. I really appreciate your help!